# Templates; constexpr ; compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

I have several questions

1)

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
void func(T t){}


int main()
{
 int i;
 double d;
 std::cin>>i;

if(i==1)
 func(i);
else
 func(d);
}
```

When (runtime/compile time) does one generate needed function? How many versions of functions are after instantiation?

2)What`s the difference between

```
template<typename T> auto func(T t){return 0;}
```

and

```
template<typename T> constexpr auto func(T t){return 0;}
```

As i understand `template` works at compile time and `constexpr` too. Why(and when) do i need to use  `constexpr` with templates?

Comment: *"When (runtime/compile time) does one generate needed function?"* Compile time, of course. *"How many versions of functions are after instantiation?"* As many as are used in the context that requires instantiation.

Comment: **(2)** The second version can be used where a compile-time constant is required: e.g. `int arr[func(42) + 1];` Roughly, `constexpr` on functions means "this function is simple and self-contained enough that a compiler can execute it at compile time; if arguments are known at compile time, the result can be, too". This is unrelated to `template` - you can happily have a non-template `constexpr` function, or a `constexpr` function template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer(1): Two versions.

Answer(2): Function instantiation and execution are two different concepts. template function is instantiated at compile time, that doesn't mean it will execute compile time. `constexpr` is different in this context as it, depending on the context where it's called and arguments, it can be generated and executed at compile time. Imagine a function declared like this

```
constexpr double myfunc(int x)
```

Now if you call it like this

```
constexpr double d1 = myfunc(1);
double d2 = myfunc(1);
```

You will have the value of d1 computed at compile time while d2 would be computed at runtime. `constexpr` is not related to template, though you can mix them together. For example here myfunc could be templatized. Would it execute compile time or run time, will depend on factors(like mentioned above).

`constexpr`, used with objects, would ensure they are compile-time initialized ( hence const by default). That's why in above case, 'context' for d1, forces myfunc to be executed compile time.